# Is there a way for scipy.integrate.quad to accept arrays in args?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, numerical-integration

I have a function:

```
def xx(th, T, B):
    f = integrate.quad(xint, 0, np.inf, args = (th, T, B))[0]
    a = v(th)*f
    return a
```

where `xint` is a function of functions of `p, th, T, B`. All the preceding functions work well; `xx(th, T, B)` should then be integrated over `th` and the other variables are single numbers.

When I run this I get: `TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars` because `th` is an array rather than a single number.

I've tried using lambda functions and also `dblquad` to do both the integrals in the same calculation but nothing has been working. Bearing in mind the limits thus trying to avoid a for loop, is there any way of getting `integrate.quad` to accept an array argument?

Traceback when run:

```
run file.py
  Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "file.py", line 280, in <module>
  file()

  File "file.py", line 240, in sctif
  axes[0, 2].plot(th, xx(th,10, 10))

  File "file.py", line 166, in xx
  f, _ = integrate.quad(xint, 0, 100,args = (th,T,B))

  File "/home/caitlin/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py", line 352, in quad
points)

  File "/home/caitlin/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py", line 463, in _quad
return _quadpack._qagse(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`
```

Comment: Where does the error occur?  If necessary show the full traceback.  The integration variable is `p`, while the values in the `args` tuple are passed to `xint` without change.  Test `xint(0, th, T, B)`.  `quad` does not do any sort of iteration over the values of those values.

Comment: The error is in the `integrate.quad` line. Full traceback:

`Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "", line 240, in 
    axes[0, 2].plot(th, xx(th,10, 10))

  File "", line 166, in xx
    f, _ = integrate.quad(xint, 0, 100,args=(th,T,B))

  File "anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py", line 352, in quad points)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py", line 463, in _quad
    return _quadpack._qagse(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`

Comment: (apologies for formatting - character limit). 

One other thing is that one of the functions forming `xint` is `v(th) = k(th) * np.cos( th - fz( th ) )` where `k( th )` is class `np.vectorize` since it was the only way I could run `optimise.newton` keeping `th` as a free variable. I have a feeling this may be an issue since a simpler code which didn't have optimisation but did have `th` as an array worked well.

Comment: it's easier to read tracebacks in an edited question

Comment: Thank you, I'll edit (never used stack before)

Answer (score 0):

I never really got the usefulness of the `args` option. IMHO, the code becomes clearer if you define a function that accepts only one argument, perhaps by wrapping:

```py
th = 2.0
T = 1.0
B = 3.0

def xint(x):
    return th * x ** B / T

f, _ = integrate.quad(xint, 0, np.inf)
```

Now, if one of `th`, `T`, `B` is a vector, your function is vector-valued, and you cannot use `quad` anymore. I'd look into `quad_vec` or [`quadpy.quad`](https://github.com/nschloe/quadpy/). (quadpy is a project of mine.)